# how to specify data on pearson correlation heatmap?

Tags: python, pearson-correlation

I have a pearson correlation heat map coded, but its showing data from my dataframe which i dont need.

is there a way to specify which columns i'd like to include?

thanks in advance

[image: pearson correlation heatmap]

```
sb.heatmap(df['POPDEN', 'RoadsArea', 'MedianIncome', 'MedianPrice', 'PropertyCount', 'AvPTAI2015', 'PTAL'].corr(), annot=True, fmt='.2f')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-832fc3c86e3e> in <module>
----> 1 sb.heatmap(df['POPDEN', 'RoadsArea', 'MedianIncome', 'MedianPrice', 'PropertyCount', 'AvPTAI2015', 'PTAL'].corr(), annot=True, fmt='.2f')

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

```
df.cov().round(3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-34a86e96b161> in <module>
----> 1 df.cov().round(3)

TypeError: cov() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the dataframe before calculating correlation

```
sns.heatmap(df[['POPDEN', 'RoadsArea', 'MedianIncome', 'MedianPrice', 'PropertyCount', 'AvPTAI2015', 'PTAL']].corr(), annot=True, fmt='.2f')
```

Comment: tried the above and am met with this error?

Comment: You need to put your columns inside a list, so do just put them inside `[]`

Comment: have i not done that?

Comment: `[]` in your code is an indexing operator, indexing operator for pandas dataframes takes either an index, a column name or list of indices/column names as input. You are not passing a list you are passing columns separated by comma. Turn it into a list by putting into another `[]`, or declare your columns list somewhere first.

Comment: ah thank you, that makes sense. annoyingly it now says TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list?

Comment: Oh wait, I assumed that you were using a pandas dataframe, it seems your `df` is not a dataframe but a list (or a list of lists), you should probably change it to a `pd.DataFrame` first

Comment: great that worked! i have added a continuation of my original issue above?

Answer (score -1):

#for multiple column selection use double square brackets.
I hope this would work

```
sb.heatmap(df[['POPDEN', 'RoadsArea', 'MedianIncome', 'MedianPrice', 'PropertyCount', 'AvPTAI2015', 'PTAL']].corr(), annot=True, fmt='.2f')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).